# Splitting Python List

Tags: list, python-2.7, split

I want to split the list below:

```
my_list = [(55, 22), (66, 33), (77, 44)]
```

I have tried:

```
a, b = my_list
```

This did not work.

What I need is:

```
a = [55,66,77]
b = [22,33,44]
```

I am looking for the simplest and easiest way.

Comment: search for `zip` in the documentation.

Comment: @thefourtheye no idea though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [18]: L = [(55, 22), (66, 33), (77, 44)]

In [19]: a,b = zip(*L)

In [20]: a
Out[20]: (55, 66, 77)

In [21]: b
Out[21]: (22, 33, 44)
```

Comment: would expect meaning of zip(*L)

Answer (score 2):

**Method-1 Using zip and map:**

```
a, b = map(list, zip(*my_list)) #this returns 2 lists 

a
[55, 66, 77]    
b
[22, 33, 44]
```

Here instead of using only `zip(*my_list)`, i have used `map` along with `zip` to get 2 lists instead of two tuples as the OP asked.

**Explaination of zip(*):** This function takes two equal-length collections, and merges them together in pairs. If we use this on 2 lists , we get the following:

```
a1 = [1,2,3]
a2 = [4,5,6]
a3 = zip(a1,a2)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Now, if you need to de-merge them, you can use `zip()` again because `zip` is its own inverse but you need use the special `*` operator. `*` operator is used to unpack values.

```
a4,a5 = zip(*a3)
a4
(1, 2, 3) #returns a tuple though
a5
(4, 5, 6) #returns a tuple though
```

**Method-2 List Comprehension:**

```
a = [x[0] for x in my_list]
b = [x[1] for x in my_list]    
a
[55, 66, 77]
b
[22, 33, 44]
```

Here, we are using list comprehension to generate two lists.

**I would suggest you use the 1st method.**

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following-

```
a, b = zip(*my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead you use zip, you can use for loop to iterate over tuples inside list

Check this code snippet

```
first_element_list =list()
>>> second_element_list = list()
>>> for i in my_list:
...     first_element_list.append(i[0])
...     second_element_list.append(i[1])
```

OR

```
first_element_list =list()
second_element_list = list()

[first_element_list.append(i[0]) for i in my_list]
[second_element_list.append(i[1]) for i in my_list]
```